# JavaScript fading Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On this site I want to fade / animate some stuff when the site is opening: http://www.coaching-starnberg.de/neu

For doing so, I'm using this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img.start').each(function(index) {
if (index == 0) { index = 1; index+=1;}
$(this).animate({opacity: "0.0"}).delay(600*index).animate({opacity: "100.0"}, 9999);
index+=1;
});
```

The HTML state of the elements are set to visible, and get hidden via JavaScript. I used this, because I wanted to be everything visible for the case, JavaScript is disabled in the Browser.

Now I noticed, that the time before JavaScript hides the elements is quite long. Meaning, **you see everything appearing at a split of a second before it's hidden** and then faded in.

How can **I diminish this time-gap, so that the content isn't shown first?**`

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're showing the elements by default, and you only hide them (and start fading) once the entire document is loaded.

Instead, you should use a no-javascript solution that does not depend on the document being loaded. A commonly used technique is to add a class "no-js" to the `<html>` element, and in the `<head>` you launch a script that just does this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = "";
```

Then in the CSS, you can set all the elements you want invisible, and for each just add:

```
.no-js [element] {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

As soon as the `<head>` is being parsed by the browser and javascript is enabled, the 'no-js' class will be removed from the html element.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply Stephan, the no-js class solution sounds sweet!I will take a deeper look into this, but I guess this will solve all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Stephan Muller's answer has been a solution.

But for my needs I found it more easy to use CSS3 **Keyframes**:

```
.element { animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}​
```

Comment: That's a nice approach as well. I'm currently working on a site that needs a no-js warning and I was thinking of doing the exact same thing  to add a little bit of extra delay :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use JavaScript for that you will always have delay. You need to hide your content with CSS initially. That's because you rely your logic on $(document).ready. This means that the browser first loads the html, the css and all javascript and then starts executing your js code. In general such things should be done with CSS.

Comment: Thanks Krasimir, your answer helped me understanding the root problem.